# Check SHA256SUMS and exit non-zero on unexpected file (file not present in digest)

Tags: authentication, checksum, integrity

I'm trying to check the integrity of a set of downloaded files using `sha256sum`.

I cryptographically signed a digest file (named `SHA256SUMS`) with PGP. I create the file by recursively calculating the checksums of all the files in & under the current directory with

```
find . -type f -not -name SHA256SUMS -exec sha256sum '{}' \; >> SHA256SUMS
```

I can now verify the integrity of the files by (after checking the signature of the digest file, which is omitted from this question for simplicity) executing:

```
sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS
```

The above command will exit non-zero if any of the files in the digest file have a different contents from what's stored in the digest file.

However, it will *not* exit non-zero if there's some new file that's not listed in the digest.

I couldn't find any options in `sha256sum` to fail if there's an unexpected file.

How can I verify the integrity of a directory recursively using `sha256sum`, including failing on unverified files?

Comment: "I couldn't find any options in `sha256sum` to fail if there's an unexpected file" –  This is because `sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS` does not traverse any directory tree, it reads pathnames from the given file. Any pathname not in the file is not its concern. You cannot find an unexpected file by just reading all expected pathnames from `SHA256SUMS` like `sha256sum -c` does; for this you need to actually traverse the directory tree like `find` does.

Comment: The functionality from the question can't be achieved using only **sha256sum**. You could parse the _SHA256SUMS_ file and compare the list of files from that file to the output of **find** (1).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sorted list of files:

```
find . -type f | sort
```

As well as a sorted list of files with checksums:

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 sha256sum
```

Then simply use `cmp`, `diff -u` or similar to compare the generated lists. If no files are added or removed, the results should be the same every time.

---

Instead of storing the file list separately, you can extract just the filenames from SHA256SUMS, for example using `cut --bytes=67-`.

Comparing just the file list (without checksums) would allow you to determine quickly whether files were added or removed, without calculating checksums for those files.

So all in all assuming your SHA256SUMS file is already present:

```
diff -u \
    <(cut --bytes=67- < SHA256SUMS) \
    <(find . -type f -not -name SHA256SUMS -print | sort)
```

If this shows no output, the file list is identical (possibly except for additional SHA256SUMS files in subdirectories, since find excludes those as well).

---

Yet another corner case is if `sha256sum` encounters files with no read permission. It would not be printed to stdout at all, so you either have to check that no errors occured when generating the list, or also capture the stderr output.